# SOAPUI Transferring Property

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, soapui

I am trying to do a transfer property in SOAP UI 3.6 prof. I am able to work it out properly. The question really is to make it random. What I mean is, in the first SOAP response, there will be a list of results and I want to pick one randomly to transfer it to second request. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a Property Transfer using XPath.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SoapUI handy but can't you use 'Groovy Script' step to select random item from your result, assign it to variable and then use in second request?

I was doing similar stuff - there are few Groovy tutorials on SoapUI website - take a look.